# communication between two services by Broadcasts

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

I try to send some data between two services using Broadcasts. The problem is: my Broadcast Receiver class don't get the data (Not getting any data from the sender) and I don't know why. I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Receiver -

```
public class Background extends Service  {

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(ActivityRecognizedService.LOCAL_BROADCAST_EXTRA);
        Log.e(TAG,message);
    }
}
```

Sender -

```
public class ActivityRecognizedService extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

private void handleDetectedActivities(List<DetectedActivity> probableActivities) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(LOCAL_BROADCAST_NAME);
    intent.putExtra(LOCAL_BROADCAST_EXTRA, str.toString());
    //LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need register your receiver in `onStartCommand`.
Something like, `registerReceiver(new MyReceiver(),new IntentFilter(LOCAL_BROADCAST_NAME))`

Comment: Thank you !! you are the best

Comment: don't forget to `unregisterReceiver` as well on you `onDestroy` method.